# Bright Data scraping browser: "Forbidden action: password typing is not allowed"

Tags: passwords, playwright-python

Using the Bright Data scraping browser via the Playwright Python library I wrote the following code snippet:

```py
await page.goto('https://example.com/login/')
await page.fill('input[name="username"]', username)
await page.fill('input[name="password"]', password)
await page.click('button[type="submit"]')
```

The username fills as expected, but on the password line, the scraping browser halts with the following error:
`Error: Forbidden action: password typing is not allowed`

I have tried other methods of entering data into the input but it seems like the scraping browser have disabled entering any kind of data into password type input fields.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Can you share the real page? If not it will be really difficult to help you.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. I'm trying to login into Brightspace using the Brightdata scraping browser. Though Im using pupetter. The exact URL is https://hetrynow.brightspace.com/d2l/login

Comment: I've just ran into this issue as well, Is there a way to disable or work around this?

Comment: @Hugo No i haven't really found an answer other than just not using Bright Data.

Answer (score 1):

Brightdata has blocked *password typing* on their end for security purposes and you would have to take  permission from them for the same.
You could approach them by opening a ticket and stating the purpose.